# Order of complexity of fibonacci functions

Tags: complexity-theory, fibonacci

I have the following three algorithms that give the Fibonacci numbers. I would like to know how I would be able to find out each of their order of complexity. Does anyone know how I might be able to determine this?

```
Method 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
long long fibb(long long a, long long b, int n) {
    return (--n>0)?(fibb(b, a+b, n)):(a);
}

Method 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
long long int fibb(int n) {
    int fnow = 0, fnext = 1, tempf;
    while(--n>0){
        tempf = fnow + fnext;
        fnow = fnext;
        fnext = tempf;
        }
        return fnext;   
}

Method 3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
long long unsigned fib(unsigned n) {
    return floor( (pow(PHI, n) - pow(1 - PHI, n))/sqrt(5) );
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but my guess would be that method one is `O(2^n)` since it is recursive, medtod 2 will be `O(n)` and the last one will be `O(1)`.

Comment: All seems to be correct

Comment: Everything seems fine.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo: I'm afraid I disagree for method 1.

Answer (score 1):

Methods 1 and 2 have complexity `O(n)`.  The reasons are straightforward:

- Method 1 recurses exactly `n-1` times, each recursion performs a simple arithmetic operation.
- Method 2 iterates exactly `n-1` times, each iteration has constant time, simple math again.

Method 3 has indeed a complexity of O(1), but may not compute the correct value, merely an approximation.

Comment: @JohnDoe: can you please click on the grey check mark below the answer score to mark it as accepted?